# Open source converter which can convert mp4 to 3gp and 3gp to mp4

Tags: open-source, video, converters, mp4, 3gp

please provide me link of good open source exe which i can call from .net and convert mp4 to 3gp and 3gp to mp4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the answer:
using ffmpeg we can do it like:

ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -r 20 -s 352x288 -b 400k -acodec libfaac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 24k file.3gp

Comment: The following converted 3GP to MP4 flawlessly for me: `ffmpeg -i input.3gp output.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at mp4box.

With ffmpeg, you usually doing remux only.
Such as,

```
ffmpeg -i " " -acodec copy -vcodec copy ....
```